Synthetic options between two underlyings
Given options (call and puts) for two given underlying pairs, A/USD and B/USD, is it possible to build synthetic options for the A/B pair?
Concrete example: spot gold (XAU/USD) is around \$2600 and silver (XAG/USD) is around \$31. So XAU/XAG is around 83.87. Given gold and silver options markets, is it possible to build eg. a gold-to-silver call option with strike 85?

To price OTC options, you can derive the implied vol of XAG/XAU  using the two implied volatilities and correlation with the Law of Cosines (triangulation rule).

Can you please provide an explicit payoff formula that you have in mind? Also, do you want to replicate that option using vanilla options, only?

@Kermittfrog Vol-driven strategies such as strangles or straddles are of main interest. European options only.

No. Say you have any portfolio with payoff in the form $f(A) + g(B)$. We can't write $(A/B-K)^+$ in this form. At $A=0,$ we would need $f(0) = -g(B)$ for all $B,$ so $g$ would be constant, which is absurd since $(A/B-K)^+$ clearly depends on $B.$
Which is not to say that the prices of options on $A$ and $B$ are entirely uninformative about the price of options on $A/B,$ or that they can't be used in any kind of hedging strategy. The fundamental modeling issue, though, is that the prices of options on $A$ and $B$ are only dependent on the marginal distributions of $A$ and $B$ whereas the price of an option on $A/B$ depends on the joint distribution.
So inevitably, new parameters (e.g. correlations) need to be introduced and marked somehow (easier said than done... especially if there aren't market prices for options on $A/B$, but even if so there are complications in practice).  And there will be risk to these new parameters that can't be hedged with options on $A$ and $B,$ though the vegas and deltas can be hedged. (Note also these greeks will of course be sensitive to the correlation... it can even flip the sign of one of the vegas.)

Thanks for your detailed yet concise answer. I suspected it was not possible to completely replicate such a portfolio, but was not entirely sure whether a dynamic strategy could do it. The point about deriving new parameters between both assets are also noteworthy.
